# extract values from callback url in node js

Tags: node.js

I am building an application using node js express and I receive a callback url like

`http://localhost:3000/callback#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI&access_token=yupojbdfklgf`

How can i extract id_token and access_token from this callback url

```
router.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
  console.log(fullUrl) // only displays /callback
  // need to read id_token and access_token here
  res.send('Hello from callback!')
});
```

Comment: try req.query.id_token and/or req.query.access_token

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
router.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
  var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
  console.log(fullUrl) // only displays /callback
  const {id_token, access_token} = req.query;
  console.log(id_token)
  console.log(access_token)
  // need to read id_token and access_token here
  res.send('Hello from callback!')
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... looking at the url I see a # where I expected to see a ? in your callback url. why is that?

Comment: Yes thats another thing if i replace # with ? i can fetch the values

Comment: What is keeping you from using a question mark instead of a #?

Comment: I am accessing someone else's url. I don't have control over it. Is there a workaround for this? I am new to node.js

Answer (score 0):

```
const url = 'http://localhost:3000/callback#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI&access_token=yupojbdfklgf'
const parsedUrl = new URL(url);
console.log(parsedUrl);
```

outputs:

```
URL {
  href: 'http://localhost:3000/callback#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI&access_token=yupojbdfklgf',
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  protocol: 'http:',
  username: '',
  password: '',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  hostname: 'localhost',
  port: '3000',
  pathname: '/callback',
  search: '',
  searchParams: URLSearchParams {},
  hash: '#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI&access_token=yupojbdfklgf'
}
```

It appears that the aforementioned `#` instead of `?` is causing the string to be in the hash property instead of query, might want check there under your `req`

If that doesn't work see if you can get the entire `req.href` and parse it from there.